# Assume $\sup_n \int_\Omega f_n \, d\mu < + \infty$. Does it follow $\sup_n f_n(x) < +\infty$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f_n \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of measurable functions w.r.t to $\mu$, being $\mu$ a *probability* measure on $\Omega$. 
>   Assume 
>   $$
> \sup_n \int_\Omega f_n \, d\mu = M < + \infty.
> $$
>   Does it follow 
>   $$
> \sup_n f_n(x) < +\infty \qquad \mu\text{-a.e. } x \in \Omega?
> $$

I am puzzled and I am getting crazy about this. This is not homework, this is a sort of self-posed problem I end up while I was solving completely different stuff.

Could you please help me? I have been trying Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem and Monotone convergence theorem but I failed. On the other hand, I tried also to construct a counterexample but I do not manage to figure out the "shape" of $f_n$... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

The answer is no. Try to construct counterexample by $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, using sequences of nonnegative functions $f_n$ supported on

$$[0,1], \left[0, \frac 12\right], \left[\frac 12, 1\right], \left[0, \frac 13\right], \left[\frac 13, \frac 23\right], \left[\frac 23, 1\right], \left[0, \frac 14\right]\cdots$$

so that $\int_0^1 f_n  = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. It was easy... The piecewise constant functions we construct have the property that $\sup_n f_n(x)=+\infty$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. Thanks a lot and sorry for the easy question.